# update two database and connect it using foreign key in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having a problem while connecting two table in database.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
     desc = models.TextField()

     def __unicode__(self):
           return self.title

class Story(models.Model):
     postTitle = models.ForeignKey(Post)
     storyTitle = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
     storyDesc = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

     def __unicode__(self):
           return self.storyTitle
```

views.py:

```
def home(req):
     return render(req, "index.html")

def create_post(request):
     title = request.POST.get('title')
     desc = request.POST.get('desc')

     storyTitle = request.POST.get('storyTitle')
     storyDesc = request.POST.get('storyDesc')

     post = Post()
     story = Story()

     post.title = title
     post.desc = desc
     post.save()

     story.storyTitle = storyTitle
     story.storyDesc = storyDesc
     story.save()

     return HttpResponse(title + " "  +desc+" "+storyTitle+" "+ storyDesc)
```

index.html:

```
<form action="/create_post/" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="id_title" name="title"/>
    <input type="text" id="id_desc" name="desc"/>
    <input type="text" id="id_storyTitle" name="storyTitle"/>
    <input type="text" id="id_storyDesc" name="storyDesc"/>
    <input type="submit" value="POST"/>
</form>
```

How to update both model Post and Story and connect Post with Story using foreign key, so that whenever I call the data of Story model then I get the same  data of Post model.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you use django forms ?

Comment: I want to use without using forms.

Comment: Any specific reason? Would make your life so much simpler.  Validations, object creation, etc...

Answer (score 0):

According to your model, `Story` object **must** have reference (foreign key) to `Post` object. So you need to create `Post` object and make reference to it in `Story` object. To do it you can simply add:

```
story.postTitle = post
```

Full `create_post` method code:

```
def create_post(request):
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    desc = request.POST.get('desc')

    storyTitle = request.POST.get('storyTitle')
    storyDesc = request.POST.get('storyDesc')

    post = Post()
    story = Story()

    post.title = title
    post.desc = desc
    post.save()

    story.postTitle = post
    story.storyTitle = storyTitle
    story.storyDesc = storyDesc
    story.save()

    return HttpResponse(title + " "  +desc+" "+storyTitle+" "+ storyDesc)
```

*Also it would be a good idea to refactor your code and rename `story.postTitle`, because it is not actually title, but reference.*

You can find more on this topic at [Django documentation - Models - Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#relationships)